# Reloading properties file without server restart

Tags: spring

I have a property file which i use to read messages from. I am using spring and hibernate in my application. I use following code to load the properties file

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1" />
    </bean>
```

I have specified cacheSeconds as 1 second so whenever i change my files cache gets refreshed so i get the changed values on my screen but on every message access cache checks the timestamp of last modification but it is not at all good for PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT 
so is there any way in which whenever i change my files those changes should automatically reflect in cache?? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JMX MBeans.It will allow you to change the property at runtime.

```
   MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
   ObjectName name = new ObjectName("org.jmxapp.tnt.jmx:type=ApplicationMessageMBean");     
   mbs.registerMBean(msg, name); // Registering MBeans
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/index.html